# For a ring homomorphism, $\phi\left ( x \right )=0$ or $\phi\left ( x \right )=x.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Question: Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a ring homomorphism.

Show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}:$ either $\phi\left ( x \right )=0$ or $\phi\left ( x \right )=x.$

I've shown that  $\phi\left ( x \right )=x$.

Now I want to show that $\phi\left ( x \right )=0$.

I begin by assuming that $\phi\left ( x \right )\neq  x$.
Then did inverse maps and using group operation preservation but to no avail.

Any hint is appreciated.

Edit: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is completely determined by the image of $1$

Note that $\phi(1)=\phi(1^2)=\phi(1)\phi(1)=(\phi(1))^2$ and so $\phi(1)=0$ or $1$

If $\phi(1)=0$, then $\phi(x)=\phi(x.1)=\phi(x).\phi(1)=0$

If $\phi(1)=1$, then $\phi(x)=x$

Comment: In a group homomorphism, e is always mapped to e. But in a ring, the homormophism does not necessarily map e to e, is this correct?

Comment: But $\phi(1) \in \mathbb{Z}$ whose square is itself, so it is either $0$ or $1$

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

$\phi(1) = \phi(1^2) = \phi(1) \cdot \phi(1) = (\phi(1))^2; \tag{1}$

(1) shows that $\phi(1) = 0$ or $\phi(1) = 1$; if $\phi(1) = 0$ then

$\phi(x) = \phi(1x) = \phi(1)\phi(x) = 0(\phi(x)) = 0 \tag{2}$

for all $x \in \Bbb Z$; if $\phi(1) \ne 0$, then $\phi(1) = 1$;  if $\phi(1) = 1$,  then

$\phi(x) = x \tag{3}$

for $x > 0$; just add $1$ to itself $x$ times.  If $x<0$ use $x + (-x) = 0$ to show $\phi(x) = -\phi(-x) = x$.